Code to do webcam capturing using the windows native API in Python's ctypes library not working as intended
So I am trying to capture webcam snapshots ctypes in Python, here is the code:
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

def CaptureWebcam(index: int, filePath: str) -> bool:
    avicap32 = ctypes.windll.avicap32
    WS_CHILD = 0x40000000
    WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 0x0400 + 10
    WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = 0x0402
    WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB = 0x0400 + 100 + 25

    hcam = avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindowW(
        wintypes.LPWSTR("Blank"),
        WS_CHILD,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetDesktopWindow(), 0
    )

    result = False

    if hcam:
        if ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(hcam, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, index, 0):
            if ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(hcam, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, 0, wintypes.LPWSTR(filePath)):
                result = True
            ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(hcam, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0)
        ctypes.windll.user32.DestroyWindow(hcam)
    
    return result

However when I run here is what is happening;
My webcam's LED indicator is turning on which means that the script is accessing my webcam however it is saving an empty file (0 Bytes) into the disk and the function is returning False.

Capture window width and height are both 0, so doesn't contain much data.

even if i make it 160, 120 like the docs say it is still not working

Best practice is to define .argtypes and .restype completely for each function, and don't mix A and W versions of APIs.
Note that HWND is a 64-bit value on 64-bit system.  .restype defaults to c_int, so a large value could be truncated.
I don't have a webcam, but below is what I would use (untested) from digging through the Windows SDK headers and sticking fully to the definitions.  Give it a try.
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

WS_CHILD = 0x40000000
WM_USER = 0x400
WM_CAP_START = WM_USER
WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 10
WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_CAP_START + 11
WM_CAP_UNICODE_START = WM_USER + 100
WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIBW = WM_CAP_UNICODE_START + 25

LRESULT = LONG_PTR = ct.c_ssize_t

avicap32 = ct.WinDLL('avicap32', use_last_error=True)
capCreateCaptureWindowW = avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindowW
capCreateCaptureWindowW.argtypes = w.LPCWSTR, w.DWORD, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, ct.c_int, w.HWND, ct.c_int
capCreateCaptureWindowW.restype = w.HWND

user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32')
GetDesktopWindow = user32.GetDesktopWindow
GetDesktopWindow.argtypes = ()
GetDesktopWindow.restype = w.HWND
SendMessageW = user32.SendMessageW
SendMessageW.argtypes = w.HWND, w.UINT, w.WPARAM, w.LPARAM
SendMessageW.restype = LRESULT
DestroyWindow = user32.DestroyWindow
DestroyWindow.argtypes = w.HWND,
DestroyWindow.restype = w.BOOL
IsWindow = user32.IsWindow
IsWindow.argtypes = w.HWND,
IsWindow.restype = w.BOOL

def AVICapSM(hwnd, m, w, l):
    return SendMessageW(hwnd, m, w, l) if IsWindow(hwnd) else 0

def capFileSaveDIB(hwnd, szName):
    s = w.LPWSTR(szName)
    return AVICapSM(hwnd, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIBW, 0, ct.cast(s, w.LPVOID).value)

def capDriverConnect(hwnd, i):
    return AVICapSM(hwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, i, 0)

def capDriverDisconnect(hwnd):
    return AVICapSM(hwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0)

def CaptureWebcam(index, filePath):
    hwnd = GetDesktopWindow()
    hcam = capCreateCaptureWindowW('Blank', WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 160, 120, hwnd, 0)
    result = False
    if hcam:
        if capDriverConnect(hcam, index):
            result = capFileSaveDIB(filePath)
            capDriverDisconnect(hcam)
        DestroyWindow(hcam)
    return result


Thanks but your code has many issues:
capDriveDisconnect is incorrectly named. It should be capDriverDisconnect.
The argtypes for capCreateCaptureWindowW is missing the square brackets [], which are needed to define the argument types as a tuple/list.
ct.cast(szName, w.LPVOID).value is problematic when passing a string to SendMessageW. The correct approach should use ctypes.create_unicode_buffer to pass the string properly.
capDriverConnect in CaptureWebcam uses the index 0 regardless of the index argument, which should be used.

capFileSaveDIB should return the result of SendMessageW, but it's returning None. It should be properly fixed to return the result of SendMessageW.

I tried modifying the code you provided by fixing the mistakes I mentioned but I still encountered the same issue where it saves an empty file

@LuckyCoder3607 Perhaps you missed "I don't have a webcam" and "untested".  It's a more accurate representation of the calls, however.  I corrected the typos. The parameter to SendMessage may need to hold a reference to the string.  FYI, commas make a tuple...() or [] not needed.

capFileSaveDIB is returning the result of SendMessageW, so not sure what you are referring to there.
